# How can I calculate global efficiency more efficiently?

Tags: python, networkx, coding-efficiency, weighted-graph, network-efficiency

I have created some code to calculate weighted global efficiency, however, the code is taking too long to run. I need to either make the code a lot more efficient or I need to find a more efficient way of calculating it for large data sets (up to 6000 points).

I have edited the code a lot and I have tried igraph (no functions for weighted global efficiency) but nothing is making it fast enough for me to get the calculations done. My current code is all displayed below

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
from networkx import algorithms 
from networkx.algorithms import efficiency 
from networkx.algorithms.efficiency import global_efficiency
from networkx.exception import NetworkXNoPath
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from itertools import permutations
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def efficiency_weighted(G, u, v, weight):
   try:
       eff = 1 / nx.shortest_path_length(G, u, v, weight='weight')
   except NetworkXNoPath:
       eff = 0
   return eff

def global_efficiency_weighted(G):
   n = len(G)
   denom = n * (n - 1)
   if denom != 0:
       g_eff = sum(efficiency_weighted(G, u, v, weight='weight') for u, v in permutations(G, 2)) / denom
   else:
       g_eff = 0
   return g_eff


data=pd.read_csv("lobe2 1.csv")
lol1 = data.values.tolist() 
data=pd.read_csv("lobe2 2.csv")
lol2 = data.values.tolist()
data=pd.read_csv("lobe2 3.csv")
lol3 = data.values.tolist()
data=pd.read_csv("lobe2 4.csv")
lol4 = data.values.tolist()
data=pd.read_csv("lobe2 5.csv")
lol5 = data.values.tolist()
data=pd.read_csv("lobe2 6.csv")
lol6 = data.values.tolist()


combos=lol1+lol2+lol3+lol4 #lists to be used for deletion in the matrix


datasafe=pd.read_csv("b1.csv", index_col=0)

##uncommennt this section for sample benchmarking
#size = 25
#subset = [c[0] for c in combos[0:size]]
#datasafe = datasafe.loc[subset, :]
#datasafe = datasafe[subset]
#combos = combos[0:size]

################################
########## Single core
################################

tic = time.time()

GE_list=[]
for combo in tqdm(combos):
   df_temp = datasafe.copy()
   df_temp.loc[combo, :] = 0
   df_temp[combo] = 0
   g=nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df_temp)
   ge=global_efficiency_weighted(g)
#    ge=global_efficiency(g) #uncomment to test non-weighted
   GE_list.append(ge)

toc = time.time()
single = toc-tic

print("results for single core")
print(GE_list)

################################
########## Multi core
################################

def multi_global(datasafe,combo):
   df_temp = datasafe.copy()
   df_temp.loc[combo, :] = 0
   df_temp[combo] = 0
   g=nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df_temp) #omptimise by zoring on adjacency
   ge=global_efficiency_weighted(g)
   return ge

tic = time.time() 

cpu = cpu_count()-1
pool = Pool(processes=cpu)

results = [pool.apply(multi_global, args=(datasafe, combo)) for combo in tqdm(combos)]

pool.close()
pool.join()
pool.terminate()

toc = time.time()
multi = toc-tic

################################
########## Multi core async
################################

def multi_global_as(datasafe,combo):
   df_temp = datasafe.copy()
   df_temp.loc[combo, :] = 0
   df_temp[combo] = 0
   g=nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df_temp) #omptimise by zoring on adjacency
   ge=global_efficiency_weighted(g)
   pbar.update(1)
   return combo,ge

tic = time.time()

cpu = cpu_count()-1
pool = Pool(processes=cpu) 
pbar = tqdm(total=int(len(combos)/cpu))

results = [pool.apply_async(multi_global_as, args=(datasafe, combo)) for combo in combos]
res=[result.get() for result in results]

pool.close()
pool.join()
pool.terminate()
pbar.close()

toc = time.time()
multi_as = toc-tic

print("results for # cpu: " + str(cpu))
print(results)
print("time for single core: "+str(single))
print("time for multi core: "+str(multi))
print("time for multi async core: "+str(multi_as))
```

the results are accurate in calculating weighted global efficiency, however, it is taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

Currently for each pair of nodes, you calculate the shortest path in the graph.  This is an expensive calculation.  While calculating the shortest path for one pair of nodes, the algorithm does a lot of work that would be useful for other pairs.  Unfortunately the information is thrown out, and then you move on to the next pair.

Instead, use [`all_pairs_dijkstra`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra) which will find the shortest paths between all pairs.

Specifically, in your call `sum(efficiency_weighted(G, u, v, weight='weight') for u, v in permutations(G, 2))` you will calculate the shortest path from u to v for each pair of nodes in `G`.  This is inefficient.

This should do the same work without the call to `efficiency_weighted`:

```
def global_efficiency_weighted(G):
   n = len(G)
   denom = n * (n - 1)
   if denom != 0:
       shortest_paths = nx.all_pairs_dijkstra(G, weight = 'weight')
       g_eff = sum(1./shortest_paths[u][0][v] if shortest_paths[u][0][v] !=0 else 0 for u, v in permutations(G, 2)) / denom
   else:
       g_eff = 0
   return g_eff
```

Comment: just to clarify, the algorithm is deleting a different 'combination' of nodes each time it runs. So each time the calculation is done it is of a different graph.

Comment: Each time you run your algorithm, the call to `sum(efficiency_weighted(G, u, v, weight='weight') for u, v in permutations(G, 2))` will be much slower than it should be because of the problem I've described.  I don't think deleting nodes will affect that.

Comment: I have sent you an email to your research account, if you could respond to it that would be great (it might be in your junk mail)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth giving iGraph a go! ;) 
Yours truly, 
Teo